# The biggest power of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the biggest value of $n$ such that  $2^n$ divide $3^{2008}-1$?

I try use main properties of congruences,  but I no Know as find the value of n. Please I need that someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2008=2^3\cdot 251$.

$$3^{2008}-1=\left(\left(3^{251}\right)^4+1\right)\left(\left(3^{251}\right)^2+1\right)\left(3^{251}+1\right)\left(3^{251}-1\right)$$

$\left(3^{251}\right)^4+1\equiv\left(3^{251}\right)^2+1\equiv 3^{251}-1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$

$3^{251}+1\equiv 4\pmod{8}$. So the answer is $5$.

---

More generally, one of the Lifting The Exponent Lemmas (LTE) says (and it's proved similarly):

> If $\upsilon_2(m)$ denotes the highest power of $2$ that divides $m$, then:
>
> If $n\ge 2$ is even and $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ are both odd, then $$\upsilon_2\left(a^n-b^n\right)=\upsilon_2(a+b)+\upsilon_2(a-b)+\upsilon_2(n)-1$$